# What does the message content in the ARINC 615A FIND protocol look like?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

I know the FIND protocol is used to discover which LRUs are available if the data loader supports the FIND protocol.  I also know the message is sent as a broadcast using UDP, but what is in the message that's being broadcasted?

Comment: ARINC 615A dataload protocol does not use ARINC 429 (ARINC 615 does). ARINC 615A uses Ethernet.

Comment: I did not tag this 429.  I am looking for 615 over Ethernet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attachment 3 of ARINC 615A-3 describes the FIND function. The FIND protocol has an Information Request (IRQ) packet and an Information Answer (IAN) packet. Each packet contains a 2 byte header and a variable length data portion.

> **3-4 Information Request Packet**
>
> Source MAC address should be the MAC address of the data loader (or
>   the initiator.
>
> Destination MAC address should be a unicast, multicast, or the
>   broadcast MAC address.
>
> Source IP Address should be the IP address of the Data loader (or the
>   initiator).
>
> Destination IP address should be a unicast, multicast, or a broadcast
>   IP address (full broadcast i.e., 255.255.255.255 or class-relevant
>   broadcast e.g., 220.130.48.255 for a class C).
>
> Opcode value should be IRQ (0x0001).
>
> Data list should be a null ASCII string with terminator: 0x00.
>
> Packet is terminated by 0x10.